# can't find regex for my usecase in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript

I'm trying to register a property from a const in a .ts file. I stringified the file through readFileSync.

The const look like this :

```
environment = {
  prop1: value,
  prop2: env.prop,
  propArray: ['','',''],
  prop: host + 'somestring',
  cancelLink: 'myvaluetocatch'
};
```

What regex would match with 'myvaluetocatch' associated with the cancelLink prop ?
If you have a way to parse a const from a .ts file without using import, could be great too :p

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The duplicate `prop:` lines are distracting me.  You know if they have exactly the same name only the last one matters, right?  Maybe if they're placeholders for the purposes of your example, you should write `prop1: value`, `prop2: env.prop`, etc.

Comment: Don't you think it's a bad idea to parse your .ts as text?  That's what TypeScript (and ultimately JavaScript) is for.  Why not refactor the bits you're looking for out into their own data files?  Use JSON if you like.

Comment: haha don't worry they have but since it's business code i replaced the original names with 'prop' or 'propArray'. I'll edit rn.

Comment: @Wyck well we are refactorising a lot of our sources (and there are really a lot, no way to do it by hand), so i'm coding a script to import those properties then write them off in a json.

Comment: You could use `cancelLink: '(.*?)'` but it REALLY depends on the style of your file.  The more you know ahead of time about what you're going to encounter, the better.

Comment: @Wyck yes thanks you ! just need to chain with a substring and it works ! Im' so bad at regex my god ^^' !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `cancelLink: '(.*?)'`, but this is fragile and depends greatly on the style of the code you have written in your file and may produce false matches.

Live regex tester with your specific example [here](https://regex101.com/r/o8kCw0/1).

Comment: The first thing I'd worry about is white space style.  (The expression matches literal space after the `:`) Then I'd be worried about matching that text in other places in your file by accident.  Adjust to suit your needs accordingly!

Comment: I'll be wary of the whitespace but it should be alright, sources files are pretty well formatted. Again thanks for answering so quickly.